# c# interface with method<T> but implement as concreate

Tags: c#

I've created an Interface like so:

```
public interface ICacheable {
    void CloneTo<T>(T entity) where T : class, new();
}
```

However, when I implement the interface in a class, I have to define the CloneTo method also using T as the type as follows:

```
public class MyEntity : ICacheable {
    public void CloneTo<T>(T genericEntity) where T : class, new() {}
}
```

This does compile and run.  However, it's not ideal as I could pass any other item that implements ICacheable to the method where I only want to be able to send an instance of the class.  What I really want is to implement it more like this:

```
public class MyEntity : ICacheable {
    public void CloneTo(MyEntity entity) {}
}
```

That way I could only pass the proper type of entity.

I tried instead creating the interface as of T, i.e.

```
public interface ICacheable<T>
```

Which did then allow me to tailor the implementing class's method to only accept that type.  However, I then could no longer have a `List<ICacheable>`.

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here?  Thanks!

Comment: How would you use a `List<ICachable>` if you don't know what the source types are?

Comment: `ICacheable <T> where T : ICacheable { void CloneTo(T entity); }` & `ICacheable : ICacheable <Entity> { }`

Comment: @Lee I have to admit it might not be the best practice way, but I have a dictionary that stores the type along with the collection if ICacheable entities.

Comment: @Brad Christie, I see... so have two interfaces, I was wondering about that route myself but couldn't get my head around it.  Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: If you need to do it dynamically create a wrapper implementing `ICacheable<object>` which checks the incoming parameter and invokes an inner generic handler.

Comment: @BradChristie I'm getting an error on the ICacheable interface that the type MyEntity cannot be used in the parameter T.  There is no implicit reference conversion.  Any ideas?

Comment: almaz's deleted post is similar to what I would have arrived at/imagined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your interface to two parts, one containing type-dependant members, another containing type-agnostic members:

```
public interface ICacheable<T> : ICacheable
    where T : class, new()
{
    // All type-dependant members go here
    void CloneTo(T entity);
}

public interface ICacheable
{
    // All type-agnostic members go here
}
```

Of course, you won't be able to use `CloneTo` with the non-generic `ICacheable` type.

Comment: Can you think of any way to cast an ICacheable to an ICacheable<T> so I can use the CloneTo method on it?  I have the type as a variable.

Comment: @Simon I may have misunderstood your question, but what about just `(ICacheable<MyType>)cacheable`? Of course, here `ICacheable` has to be an `ICacheable<MyType>`, or you will get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime. You can check type correctness by `if(cacheable is ICacheable<MyType>)`

Comment: thanks.  The problem I've got it, I put the collection of ICacheable objects into a dictionary, the key being their Type.  When I then retrieve them and want to call CloneTo, although I have the type as a variable, I can't cast to it, or at least, not at compile time - I need a way to do it as runtime.  Any idea?

Comment: @Simon The point of generics is to have strong typing. Since you're storing your `ICacheable`s by `Type`, you won't have strong typing anyway. And you can't cast variables by just having a runtime `Type`. You should probably reconsider your design, and just go by using `object` instead of a generic `T`. That would save you all this trouble, since I can tell you're probably using some reflection voodoo anyway.

Comment: thanks, I think you are right and I've over complicated it a bit where it perhaps didn't need to be.  I've gone back to just the non-generic ICacheable interface and in my CloneTo method, just do a check that the supplied object is of the implementing classes type.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have `List<ICacheable<MyEntity>>` you can always have `List<object>`.

Only other organization I can think off is something like:

```
public interface ICacheable
{
    void CloneTo(ICacheable entity);
}

public interface ICacheable<T> : ICacheable where T : ICacheable
{
    void CloneTo(T entity);
}

public abstract class Cacheable<T> : ICacheable<T> where T : ICacheable
{
    void ICacheable.CloneTo(ICacheable entity)
    {
        // here it can fail at runtime though
        CloneTo((T)entity);
    }

    public abstract void CloneTo(T entity);
}

public class MyEntity : Cacheable<MyEntity>
{
    public override void CloneTo(MyEntity entity)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So you can have:

```
var list = new List<ICacheable>();
list.Add(new MyEntity());
var something = new MyEntity();
// works 
list[0].CloneTo(something);
```

However you can run into issues with code like:

```
public class SecondEntity : Cacheable<SecondEntity> { ... }
var list = new List<ICacheable>();
list.Add(new MyEntity());
var something = new SecondEntity();
// oops - runtime error
list[0].CloneTo(something);
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I really want is to implement it more like this:

```
public class MyEntity : ICacheable {
  public void CloneTo(MyEntity entity) {}
}
```

> Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

The restriction you wish to express cannot be expressed in the C# type system. You'd need a "higher" type system; this restriction could be expressed in Haskell for instance. (Though I would not care to say how; I am no expert on Haskell!)

This does not stop people from trying; I describe the most common "broken" way I see to implement this restriction here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/

I do not recommend that you attempt this curious pattern. Rather than tying the C# type system in knots to try to express a particular restriction, ask yourself what the polymorphism inherent in defining an interface really buys you and your users. Go back to the key user scenarios and see if there is another way to describe your scenario.

For example, here you're trying to represent "a cachable entity may be cloned to another entity".  Great. That's the scenario. There is no requirement that you implement that with an ICacheable interface that has a CloneTo method.  You could for example say that entities have a "clone from" method. See if that is easier to express in the type system. Or you could say that there is a bigger abstraction here: that some entities may contain clones of others, and whether or not any particular pair of entities have that relationship can be determined by a policy engine; now you must design and implement that engine.  And so on. Not every business problem needs to be solved by embedding its rules in the type system.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this.  You were indeed right that the solution was to step back and see if there was a better (or at least, a different and achievable) solution.

Comment: @Eric: I agree with "Not every business problem needs to be solved by embedding its rules in the type system." However, this specific scenario seems to be very common hence the "curious pattern". I personally would have liked to express those relationships via the language itself a few times. I read your article about it and again I agree that the pattern is not intuitive, but the concept it tries to model is indeed intuitive IMHO. I know you haven't been involved with MS for a while, but I'm curious (haha) if the possibility of baking support for that case into C# was ever considered?

Comment: @FrankJ: I don't recall that particular pattern ever being considered. The C# team certainly does consider changing aspects of the type system - covariance was my feature for C# 4 for instance - but representing higher-kinded-type patterns would require changes not just to C# but to the underlying type CLR generic type system. It could be done, but there are probably better ways to spend that effort.

Comment: @Eric: Makes sense, I figure there are more interesting features higher on the list than this, so I'm not really holding my breath that this gets ever added. That being said all in all I love the features that have been added over the years and as a user I just want always more to help me with my "problem of the day".

Comment: It would be nice if you *could* embed all business rules in the type system. Isn't that how you acheive correctness that can be checked by a computer?

Comment: @MarkCidade: That is a deep question that would take more than the length of a comment to answer. I wrote a series of blog posts exploring one small corner of this general problem space; you might find it interesting. http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/